assembly 8086 random numbers
I am trying to roll a random number in the range 0-7 i wrote this code
    mov ax, 40h
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, [es:6Ch]
    and al, 00001000b

this code always gives me 0 as a result and i don't understand why.
what can i do or change so it will generate a random number in the range of 0-7?
i tried to solve the 'and' with the number i got and the 1000b and i don't understand why it doesn't work. and i tried to change the number in of the 'and' and it made it work but then its not the range i need.

What are you expecting this to do, step by step?

i want it to roll a random number between 0 and 7

What do you want each instruction to do to accomplish that ultimate goal?

Do you know the possible values left as a result of and al, 00001000b ?

Note that and al, 00001000b will only ever produce two values since you only keep 1 bit. You want to keep the low 3 bits instead.


this code always gives me 0 as a result and i don't understand why.

Actually your code will produce half of the time 0 and the other half of the time 8. The same value will last for about 0.5 sec because the BIOS timer that you are using operates at about 18.2 Hz.
If you use the and instruction, then remember the truth table for the AND operation:
false and false : false
false and true  : false
true  and false : false
true  and true  : true

Only when corresponding bits in the two operands are set to 1, will you get a 1 in the result.

what can i do or change so it will generate a random number in the range of 0-7?

Use another AND mask:
01010101b   10101010b
00001000b   00001000b   AND mask is 8
--------    --------
00000000b   00001000b
    |           |
     \----------+-------------- 2 possible outcomes {0,8} 

01010101b   10101010b
00000111b   00000111b   AND mask is 7
--------    --------
00000101b   00000010b
     |||         |||
      \-----------+------------ 8 possible outcomes [0,7]

A random number derived directly from the BIOS timer can only be good enough if you don't need one too often. Every 2-3 seconds could be fine.
If you need more frequently random numbers, then see a better 8086 random number generator (not just using the system time)?.
